# HTML Special Character Codes translation in text XSLT 2.0

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-2.0, html-escape-characters, unicode-escapes

I receive text from source system with HTML special escape characters  in middle of text. Now I need to translate it to the actual character in XSLT 2.0

I/p like

```
<Data>Lenevo100 f&amp;uuml;r Laser</Data>
<Data>DELL &amp;Agrave;llow Drucker</Data>
```

and the expected output would be

```
<DataOutput>Lenevo100 fÜr Laser</DataOutput>
<DataOutput>DELL Àllow Drucker</DataOutput>
```

If it is always only 2 or 3 values i can do the replace or translate function but the problem is this HTML special code characters are so many .Can any provide the solution to achieve this,

List of HTML special characters code **https://www.ou.edu/research/electron/internet/special.shtml**

Comment: There may be solutions specific to a particular XSLT processor or execution platform. Let us know which product you are using for your XSLT 2.0 library.

Comment: I am using this XSLT 2.0 Oracle  Cloud OIC product

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor is used in Oracle Cloud OIC? Does it allow you to use Java libraries from XSLT so that you could call into an HTML parser?

Comment: No it wont allow to call Java libraries.

Comment: What about my posted answer, to use the XSLT library parsing HTML/HTML entity references? Can't you use that either?

Comment: Hi Martin,  I checked the XSLT library and it's also not allowing.

Comment: Well, you don't have to import from the given URL, you can also download and then save to a location from which the cloud processor does allow an `xsl:import` or `xsl:include`. If you can't `xsl:import` or `xsl:include` anything, you can try to copy the code from the library inline into your own XSLT.

Comment: Sure Martin, let me try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle has an HTML parser written in XSLT 2.0, it is online at https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl, you can use it as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dpc="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <DataOutput>
      <xsl:value-of select="dpc:htmlparse(., '', true())"/>
    </DataOutput>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```